# Pass Google Script Array to Javascript Function (Google Apps)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I understand why my code does not work, however I can't find a solution searching online. Likely a simple syntax correction. Here is the code:

### Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
   .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
 }

 function getData() {
   return SpreadsheetApp
  .openById('My Sheet ID')
  .getActiveSheet()
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues();
 }
```

### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
    h1 {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ABC;
    }
    #wrapper { 
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
  <h1>Attendace Discrepancy Tracker v1.0</h1>

  <h3>Discrepancy date:</h3><input type="date" name="bday" min="2000-01-02"><br>

    <? var data = getData(); ?> <------ Gets data from my sheet

    <h3>Select a name:</h3><select id='empName' onchange="findEmpID();">
      <? for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
            <option value="<?= i ?>"><?= data[i][2] + ", " + data[i][1] + " " + data[i][3]?></option>
      <? } ?>

    </select>

    <div id="empProfile">
      <p>Employee Number: <span id="empNumber"></span></p>
      <p>Supervisor: <span id="empSup"></span></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      function findEmpID () {
        var e = document.getElementById("empName");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById("empNumber")
        .innerHTML = <?= data[strUser][0] ?>; <----- This does not work
      }

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The whole program works, except when I try and reference back to the `data` array. I need a way to pass the `<script>` tags `strUser` value to the `data` array google script variable so I can get the supervisors ID number. Obviously when I switch to the `<?` tag space it cannot read variables from the `<script>` tag. I am sure it is possible, just have not figured out how.

Comment: I have discovered that when you pass an array from `Google Script` it does not keep its array form. Instead it becomes a VERY long string. I suppose if I can break down that string I could have a solution, but this seems a bit much.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a scriptlet after the HTML has loaded.  It looks like you are trying to trigger the scriptlet to run from the `onchange` attribute of the drop down list.  I don't think that scriptlets will run except when the page is first loaded.

I'd change things like this:

Use the `this` keyword to pass the employee name to the client side `findEmpID()` function:

```
<h3>Select a name:</h3><select id='empName' onchange="findEmpID(this.value);">
```

Note the use

of `this.value`.  Enter a variable name in the function parenthesis to receive the employee name:

```
function findEmpID(theName) {
```

Pass the name to the server function:

```
<script>
  function findEmpID(theName) {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(enterName)
      .getThisEmployeeID(theName);
  };

  function enterName(theReturnedName) {
    //Put the name into the HTML Element
    document.getElementById("empNumber").textContent = theReturnedName;
  };
</script>
```

You'll need to get the data from the spreadsheet, and find the name with the server function:

GS code

```
function getThisEmployeeID(theName) {
  //Get range of data
  var arrayOfData = sheet.getRange(parameters).getValues();
  //I don't know how the data is configured, but you'll need to match
  //the name to the index number in the array, then get the ID

  var employeeID = 'xyz';
  return employeeID;
};
```